# How to divide a matrix into equals parts?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let's say I have a 100x100 matrix, I want to divide it into equal parts of 10x10.

The problem is that the input matrix can be of any size (but always mod 10).
I looked at the `mat2cell` function but it does not seem to work for a dynamic number of parts.
Or am I missing something?

Comment: If your goal is to ultimately process these sub-matrices, perhaps you want to consider using the block processing functions in the Image Processing Toolbox (ex: **blockproc**), refer to: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/f7-12726.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just have to tell `mat2cell` exactly how you want the matrix divided up.  If you're positive that it is always going to be a multiple of 10 in both directions, then it is (fairly) simple.  Assuming that `X` is the matrix that you want to divide, and you want the resulting cell array in `Y`:

`Y = mat2cell(X, repmat(10,[1 size(X,1)/10]), repmat(10,[1 size(X,2)/10]));`