# How can I divide a matrix into unequally-sized submatrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

I am wondering if it is possible to use the `mat2cell` function to divide an `MxN` matrix into 10 submatrices with the same column size, `N`, and approximately the same row size `~M/10`? If `mod(M, 10) == 0` then all submatrices will have the same size, otherwise a few matrices will have +/-1 row. Is this possible via the `mat2cell` function?

For reference, if the row sizes are all the same it's fairly straightforward, as explained here:

[How to divide a matrix into equals parts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1817174/52738)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using the functions [`linspace`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html), [`round`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html), and [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html):

```
[M, N] = size(mat);  % Matrix size
nSub = 10;           % Number of submatrices
cMat = mat2cell(mat, diff(round(linspace(0, M, nSub+1))), N);
```

This approach will distribute extra rows in a more uniform fashion across the resulting cells of the cell array. Note these outputs that you will get when applying the above using `mat = magic(5);` (left) and `mat = magic(13);` (right):

```
cMat =              cMat = 

    [1x5 double]        [1x13 double]
    [0x5 double]        [2x13 double]
    [1x5 double]        [1x13 double]
    [0x5 double]        [1x13 double]
    [1x5 double]        [2x13 double]
    [0x5 double]        [1x13 double]
    [1x5 double]        [1x13 double]
    [0x5 double]        [1x13 double]
    [1x5 double]        [2x13 double]
    [0x5 double]        [1x13 double]
```

If you'd prefer a random distribution of extra rows, you can use [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) like so:

```
subSizes = diff(round(linspace(0, M, nSub+1)));
cMat = mat2cell(mat, subSizes(randperm(nSub)), N);
```

Comment: +1 - I think this is better than what I provided (unless one wants the extra rows clumped in the front).

Comment: @sage: As with many problems in MATLAB, there are usually a number of equally good solutions. It's just a matter of where you want the extra rows. ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is possible and is similar to the link you provided, but you need to decide how you want to divide up the 'leftover' rows when M mod 10 is not 0 and what you will do if there are fewer than 10 rows to begin with.  The following should work if the listed assumptions are valid:

```
[M,N] = size(X);
Y = mat2cell(X, [repmat(ceil(M/10),[1 mod(M,10)]) ...
                 repmat(floor(M/10),[1 10-mod(M,10)])], N);
```

Assumptions:

1. You will have >= 10 rows (or you don't mind having 0xN arrays)
2. You are content to have the additional rows divided among the first matrices - i.e. if you have 13 rows, then you have 3 consecutive matrices with 2 rows, followed by 7 matrices of 1 row.

For instance, I ran this on X = eye(7) and got:

```
Y = 
 [1x7 double]
   ...
 [1x7 double]
 [0x7 double]
 [0x7 double]
 [0x7 double]
```