# MATLAB using MAT2CELL

Tags: matlab, matrix

i have the following matrices

```
letter=[A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z ...
        a b c d e f g h ii jj k l m o p q r s t u v w x y z];

number=[one two three four five six seven eight nine zero];

character =[number letter];
```

Character becomes a matrix of 42 by 1464, but i would like to break it into cells of 42 by 24 using mat2cell.
How can i please do it, every time i try i get an error????

Answer (score 4):

The example matrices you give don't make much sense given the problem you describe in the text. If you have a matrix of size 42-by-1464, and you want to use [MAT2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mat2cell.html) to break it up into a cell array containing elements that are 42-by-24, you can do the following:

```
mat = repmat('a',42,1464);  %# A sample character matrix containing all 'a's
[nRows nCols] = size(mat);  %# Get the number of rows and columns in mat
nSubCols = 24;              %# The number of desired columns in each submatrix
cellArray = mat2cell(mat,nRows,nSubCols.*ones(1,nCols/nSubCols));
```

The second input to [MAT2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mat2cell.html) defines how the rows will be broken up among cells along the row dimension. In this case, a single value of 42 (i.e. `nRows`) indicates that the resulting cell array will have one row and the cells will contain matrices with 42 rows.

The third input to [MAT2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mat2cell.html) defines how the columns will be broken up among cells along the column dimension. In this case, it is a 61 element (i.e. `nCols/nSubCols`) row vector whose elements all contain the number 24 (i.e. `nSubCols`). This indicates that the resulting cell array will have 61 columns and the cells will contain matrices with 24 columns.

The net result is that `cellArray` ends up being a 1-by-61 cell array where each cell contains a 42-by-24 submatrix of `mat`.

The above works when `nCols` is an exact multiple of `nSubCols`. If it isn't, then you will have to distribute columns to your cells in a heterogeneous manner (i.e. each cell may have a different number of columns in its submatrix). Some ways to deal with such a situation are discussed in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550136/mat2cell-to-divide-matrix-of-size-mxn-into-10-submatrices).

Comment: Exactly what I was about to post as well (though I would have written 61 instead of 1461/24). +1