# Error in calculating perspective transform for opencv in Matlab

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, perspectivecamera

I am trying to recode [feature matching and homography](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html) using [mexopencv](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv) .Mexopencv ports OpenCV vision toolbox into Matlab .

My code in Matlab using OpenCV toolbox:

```
function hello

    close all;clear all;

    disp('Feature matching demo, press key when done');

    boxImage = imread('D:/pic/500_1.jpg');

    boxImage = rgb2gray(boxImage);

    [boxPoints,boxFeatures] = cv.ORB(boxImage);

    sceneImage = imread('D:/pic/100_1.jpg');

    sceneImage = rgb2gray(sceneImage);

    [scenePoints,sceneFeatures] = cv.ORB(sceneImage);

    if (isempty(scenePoints)|| isempty(boxPoints)) 
        return;
    end;


    matcher = cv.DescriptorMatcher('BruteForce');
    matches = matcher.match(boxFeatures,sceneFeatures);


    %Box contains pixels coordinates where there are matches
    box = [boxPoints([matches(2:end).queryIdx]).pt];

    %Scene contains pixels coordinates where there are matches
    scene = [scenePoints([matches(2:end).trainIdx]).pt];

    %Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682927/matlab-using-mat2cell

    %Box arrays contains coordinates the form [ (x1,y1), (x2,y2) ...]
    %after applying mat2cell function
    [nRows, nCols] = size(box);
    nSubCols = 2;
    box = mat2cell(box,nRows,nSubCols.*ones(1,nCols/nSubCols));

    %Scene arrays contains coordinates the form [ (x1,y1), (x2,y2) ...]
    %after applying mat2cell function

    [nRows, nCols] = size(scene);
    nSubCols = 2;
    scene = mat2cell(scene,nRows,nSubCols.*ones(1,nCols/nSubCols));

    %Finding homography between box and scene
    H = cv.findHomography(box,scene);

    boxCorners = [1, 1;...                           % top-left
        size(boxImage, 2), 1;...                 % top-right
        size(boxImage, 2), size(boxImage, 1);... % bottom-right
        1, size(boxImage, 1)];

  %Fine until this point , problem starts with perspectiveTransform   
  sceneCorners= cv.perspectiveTransform(boxCorners,H); 

end
```

The error:

```
    Error using cv.perspectiveTransform
Unexpected Standard exception from MEX file.
What()
is:C:\slave\builds\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\core\src\matmul.cpp:1926:
error: (-215) scn + 1 == m.cols && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_64F)

..

Error in hello (line 58)
  sceneCorners= cv.perspectiveTransform(boxCorners,H);
```

The problem starts from checking out the `perspectiveTranform(boxCorners, H)`, until finding `homography` it was fine . Also note that while calculating the matching coordinates from the sample and the scene , I indexed from `2:end`,  `box = [boxPoints([matches(2:end).queryIdx]).pt]`, since accessing the `queryIdx` of the 1st element would yield the zeroth position that couldn't be accessed . However , I think , this would not be a problem . Anyhow , I am looking forward for an answer to my solution . Thanks.

***PS:This is an edited version of my original post here . The solution I received below ,was not adequate enough , and the bug kept recurring .***

#### **2nd Update:**

According to @Amro , I have updated my code ,below . The inliers gives good response , however the coordinates for calculating perspective transform somehow got twisted.

```
function hello
    close all; clear all; clc;

    disp('Feature matching with ORB');

    %Feature detector and extractor for object
    imgObj = imread('D:/pic/box.png');
    %boxImage = rgb2gray(boxImage);
    [keyObj,featObj] = cv.ORB(imgObj);

    %Feature detector and extractor for scene
    imgScene = imread('D:/pic/box_in_scene.png');
    %sceneImage = rgb2gray(sceneImage);
    [keyScene,featScene] = cv.ORB(imgScene);

    if (isempty(keyScene)|| isempty(keyObj)) 
        return;
    end;

    matcher = cv.DescriptorMatcher('BruteForce-HammingLUT');
    m = matcher.match(featObj,featScene);

    %im_matches = cv.drawMatches(boxImage, boxPoints, sceneImage, scenePoints,m);

    % extract keypoints from the filtered matches
    % (C zero-based vs. MATLAB one-based indexing)
    ptsObj = cat(1, keyObj([m.queryIdx]+1).pt);
    ptsObj = num2cell(ptsObj, 2);
    ptsScene = cat(1, keyScene([m.trainIdx]+1).pt);
    ptsScene = num2cell(ptsScene, 2);

    % compute homography
    [H,inliers] = cv.findHomography(ptsObj, ptsScene, 'Method','Ransac');

    % remove outliers reported by RANSAC
    inliers = logical(inliers);
    m = m(inliers);

    % show the final matches
    imgMatches = cv.drawMatches(imgObj, keyObj, imgScene, keyScene, m, ...
    'NotDrawSinglePoints',true);
    imshow(imgMatches);

    % apply the homography to the corner points of the box
    [h,w] = size(imgObj);
    corners = permute([0 0; w 0; w h; 0 h], [3 1 2]);
    p = cv.perspectiveTransform(corners, H)
    p = permute(p, [2 3 1])
    p = bsxfun(@plus, p, [size(imgObj,2) 0]);

    % draw lines between the transformed corners (the mapped object)
    opts = {'Color',[0 255 0], 'Thickness',4};
    imgMatches = cv.line(imgMatches, p(1,:), p(2,:), opts{:});
    imgMatches = cv.line(imgMatches, p(2,:), p(3,:), opts{:});
    imgMatches = cv.line(imgMatches, p(3,:), p(4,:), opts{:});
    imgMatches = cv.line(imgMatches, p(4,:), p(1,:), opts{:});
    imshow(imgMatches)
    title('Matches & Object detection')

end
```

The output is fine , however , the `perspectiveTranform` is not giving the right coordinates apropos to the problem .
My output thus far :

[image: Output]

#### **3rd Update:**

I have got all of the code running and fine with the homography . However , a corner case is bugging me really hard .
If I do `imgObj = imread('D:/pic/box.png')` and `imgScene = imread('D:/pic/box_in_scene.png')` , I get the homography rectangle good and fine , however , when I do `imgScene = imread('D:/pic/box.png')` , i.e the object and scene are the *same* , I get this error -

```
Error using cv.findHomography
Unexpected Standard exception from MEX file.
What()
is:C:\slave\builds\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\fundam.cpp:1074:
error: (-215) npoints >= 0 && points2.checkVector(2) == npoints && points1.type() ==
points2.type()

..

Error in hello (line 37)
    [H,inliers] = cv.findHomography(ptsObj, ptsScene, 'Method','Ransac');
```

Now , I have came across this error in the past , this happens when the number of `ptsObj` or `ptsScene` is low , e.g, when the scene is nothing but a white/black screen , keypoints of that scene is zero . In this particular problem there is ample amount of `ptsObj` and `ptsScene`. Where can the problem lie . I have tested this code using `SURF`an the same error is resurfacing .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of remarks:

- the matcher returns zero-based indices (as well as various other functions on account of OpenCV being implemented in C++). So if you want to get the corresponding keypoints you have to adjust by one (MATLAB arrays are one-based). `mexopencv` [intentionally](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/issues/23#issuecomment-9932269) does not automatically adjust for this.
- The [`cv.findHomography`](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/blob/master/src/+cv/findHomography.cpp#L48) MEX-function accepts points either as a numeric array of size `1xNx2` (e.g: `cat(3, [x1,x2,...], [y1,y2,...])`) or as an `N`-sized cell array of two-element vectors each (i.e `{[x1,y1], [x2,y2], ...}`). In this case, I'm not sure your code is packing the points correctly, either way it could be made much simpler..

Here is the complete [demo](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html) translated from C++ to MATLAB:

```
% input images
imgObj = imread('box.png');
imgScene = imread('box_in_scene.png');

% detect keypoints and calculate descriptors using SURF
detector = cv.FeatureDetector('SURF');
keyObj = detector.detect(imgObj);
keyScene = detector.detect(imgScene);

extractor = cv.DescriptorExtractor('SURF');
featObj = extractor.compute(imgObj, keyObj);
featScene = extractor.compute(imgScene, keyScene);

% match descriptors using FLANN
matcher = cv.DescriptorMatcher('FlannBased');
m = matcher.match(featObj, featScene);

% keep only "good" matches (whose distance is less than k*min_dist )
dist = [m.distance];
m = m(dist < 3*min(dist));

% extract keypoints from the filtered matches
% (C zero-based vs. MATLAB one-based indexing)
ptsObj = cat(1, keyObj([m.queryIdx]+1).pt);
ptsObj = num2cell(ptsObj, 2);
ptsScene = cat(1, keyScene([m.trainIdx]+1).pt);
ptsScene = num2cell(ptsScene, 2);

% compute homography
[H,inliers] = cv.findHomography(ptsObj, ptsScene, 'Method','Ransac');

% remove outliers reported by RANSAC
inliers = logical(inliers);
m = m(inliers);

% show the final matches
imgMatches = cv.drawMatches(imgObj, keyObj, imgScene, keyScene, m, ...
    'NotDrawSinglePoints',true);
imshow(imgMatches)

% apply the homography to the corner points of the box
[h,w] = size(imgObj);
corners = permute([0 0; w 0; w h; 0 h], [3 1 2]);
p = cv.perspectiveTransform(corners, H);
p = permute(p, [2 3 1]);
p = bsxfun(@plus, p, [size(imgObj,2) 0]);

% draw lines between the transformed corners (the mapped object)
opts = {'Color',[0 255 0], 'Thickness',4};
imgMatches = cv.line(imgMatches, p(1,:), p(2,:), opts{:});
imgMatches = cv.line(imgMatches, p(2,:), p(3,:), opts{:});
imgMatches = cv.line(imgMatches, p(3,:), p(4,:), opts{:});
imgMatches = cv.line(imgMatches, p(4,:), p(1,:), opts{:});
imshow(imgMatches)
title('Matches & Object detection')
```

[image: matches_homography]

Now you can try one of the other algorithms for feature detection/extraction (ORB in your case). Just remember you might need to adjust some of the parameters above to get good results (for example the multiplier used to control how many of the keypoint matches to keep).

---

### EDIT:

Like I said, there is no one size fits all solution in computer vision. You need to experiment by adjusting the various algorithm parameters to get good results on your data. For instance, the [ORB constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#orb-orb) accepts a bunch of options. Also as the documentation [suggests](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#bfmatcher-bfmatcher), the brute force matcher with Hamming distances is a recommended matcher for ORB descriptors.

Finally note that I specified [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) robust algorithm as method used for computing the homography matrix; Looking at the screenshot you posed, you can see an [outlier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) match incorrectly pointing towards the black computer vision book in the scene. The advantage of the RANSAC method is that it can accurately perform estimation even when there is a large number of outliers in the data. The default method used by [`findHomography`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography) is to use all the points available.

Furthermore note that some of the control points used to estimate the homography in you case are almost co-linear, this might badly contribute to the computation (kind of like how numerically inverting a matrix close to singular is a bad idea).

With the above said, I am highlighting below the relevant parts of the code which gave me good results using ORB descriptors (the rest is unchanged from what I previously posted):

```
% detect keypoints and calculate descriptors using ORB
[keyObj,featObj] = cv.ORB(imgObj);
[keyScene,featScene] = cv.ORB(imgScene);

% match descriptors using brute force with Hamming distances
matcher = cv.DescriptorMatcher('BruteForce-Hamming');
m = matcher.match(featObj, featScene);

% keep only "good" matches (whose distance is less than k*min_dist )
dist = [m.distance];
m = m(dist < 3*min(dist));
```

[image: ORB_matching]

I noticed that you omitted the last part where I filtered the matches by dropping bad ones.. You could always look at the distribution of the "distances" of the matches found, and decide on an appropriate threshold. Here is what I had initially:

```
hist([m.distance])
title('Distribution of match distances')
```

[image: match_distances_distribution]

You could also apply similar process on the raw keypoints based on their response values, and subsample the points accordingly:

```
subplot(121), hist([keyObj.response]); title('box')
subplot(122), hist([keyScene.response]); title('scene')
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks , let me try different varieties of it and will then let you .

Comment: I have done it with orb , the coordinates from perspective transform got twisted , so ... a little bit analysis out here .

Comment: Another comment : @Amro , if I just replace SURF with ORB in your code with BruteForce-Hamming matcher , I still receive the same image output , as my 2nd update shows .

Comment: @whoknows: see my edit. I guess it takes only a few outliers to completely mess up the results!

Comment: Great observation ; I fixed my result . One final note , its just out of your experience . I want to do matching on live streaming data from webcam , do you think 'ORB' used in Matlab will give me substantial boost up in performance , compared to the use of 'SURF'. Will Matlab's overhead will still be the dominating factor regardless of what algorithm I use for extraction and detection -- and it will be better off if I consider using OpenCV with C++ only .

Comment: @whoknows: Obviously there is some overhead for the MEX-wrappers, but it shouldn't be too bad. The only possible downside I see is that many of OpenCV C++ functions can perform operations in-place, but since MEX-functions are not allowed to change their input (at least not in a documented way), a copy will be made instead... Overall the advantage is that a language like MATLAB enables you quickly prototype such an application. As for real-time performance, you'll have to implement it and see for yourself :)

Comment: .. Check [this page](http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/07/comparison-of-the-opencvs-feature-detection-algorithms-ii/) for a comparison of OpenCV's feature detection algorithms.

Comment: I think I would accept your answer . I hope I can reach you via mail or something if I have further problems along the way . Thanks anyway for your insightful comments .

Comment: Unfortunate bug , can you please see my latest update .

Comment: @whoknows: thats because the matches returned are perfect (one-to-one) with all the distances equal to zero. Hence the filtering step will prune all of them, causing `cv.findHomograpy` to fail because it is getting zeros points... Again if you looked at the histogram as I did before you will understand the issue (it will be only one peak!). Obviously you'll need to include some sanity checks when applying the above "good matches" naive heuristic :)

Comment: @whoknows: btw the fix is super easy, just change the test to "less-than **or-equal**" (`<=`): `m = m(dist <= 3*min(dist));`

Comment: Yep , sometimes I even forget the basic constructs .

Comment: I have almost completed coding my project . It was supposed to take live stream data , and compare the scene with a database of image . However , there is a problem , how do I say that image_1 is more  similar to image_2 than to image_3 . Do I look for the size of inliers that the matching between scene and object produces, and then look for the biggest inlier count. I am currently doing so, however, I am getting a lot of false positive, for which I cannot have a stable way of saying that I got a match.

Comment: The only other way is to see visually for the match, and that isn't effective way to respond to a user. I was also thinking about taking square of corresponding points between object and scene . The value of which will be smallest during a very good match , i,e when I will see a rectangle around the scene in question. I know its sound absurd, so little bit of help required ,to somehow convey to user that a match is found .My working code is here http://pastebin.com/dv0KfJvG , the post here is already long .

Answer (score 2):

The functions in the Image Processing Toolbox and the Computer Vision System Toolbox use a different convention for transforming points from what you see in most textbooks.  In most textbooks, the points are represented in column vectors.  So your transformation look like this: H * x, where H is the transformation matrix, and x is a matrix whose columns are the points.

In MATLAB, on the other hand, the points are typically represented as row vectors. So you have to switch the order of the multiplication and transpose H: x' * H'.

Finally, if you have the Computer Vision System Toolobx for MATLAB, you can solve your problem with less code.  Check out this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/detect-objects-in-a-cluttered-scene-using-point-feature-matching.html).

Comment: Thanks for the example in the link , greatly appreciated . Just one another query , I want to match the surf detectors against a database of image using opencv , is there any tutorial for that . I know OpenCV website hosts an example to match one test image against a train image . I want that to be for multiple training image. Link is http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html

Comment: The naive way to do this, is to match your test image pairwise to each of the images in your database.  A better way to do this is to store the feature descriptors from the database images in a KD-tree and use approximate nearest neighbors.  OpenCV includes something called FLANN that does that. The Statistics Toolbox for MATLAB has a KDTreeSearcher object.

Comment: I do not want to be a user vampire , but can you provide me some feedback from this problem , any thoughtful comments will do . There is an image at the bottom comment .Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329255/perspective-transform-not-calculating-proper-lines-on-scene-in-matlab

Comment: Many thanks for the link . I managed to finish my project almost . Lets see what my teacher thinks about it .

Comment: @Dima: for what its worth, many of the functions in the Computer Vision Toolbox are based on OpenCV (Mathworks built their own MEX wrappers) :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the transposition of H.

We compute the homography matrix as: x'=H*x, but in MATLAB, it seems like this type: x'^{T}=x^{T}*H^{T} ( x'^{T} denoted the transposition of x' ). So, transpose your homography and try again.

Comment: Just to make clear the input to the perspective transform function needs to be transposed in the above setting .