# Perspective transform not calculating proper lines on scene in Matlab

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

So , I have trying to write equivalent code for [homography](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html) example given in OpenCV . The code is pretty long but is very concise , at first it calculates the detectors and descriptors of an object and a scene(via webcam) . It then makes comparison between them using `BruteForce Matcher` . It then chooses the best matches and use that to calculate the `homography` and afterwards `perspective transform` of the object and the scene . Now my problem is that the `perspective transform` is not giving me a good result . On of the coordinates obtained by `perspective transform` seems to hang around the `(0,0)` coordinates . I have a similar code running in pure OpenCV in eclipse , from which I saw that the first coordinate change when I move around the camera , its not happening . Also to note that the `homography` value calculated is slightly different . However , to me there is no problem with the logic of the code .But , the rectangular region is not properly shown in the scene. I **can see** different lines being drawn on the scene,but they are not fitting the image , as well as it should .Perhaps I need a different set of eyes . Thanks.

```
function hello

    disp('Feature matching demo. Press any key when done.');

    % Set up camera
    camera = cv.VideoCapture;
    pause(3); % Necessary in some environment. See help cv.VideoCapture

    % Set up display window
    window = figure('KeyPressFcn',@(obj,evt)setappdata(obj,'flag',true));
    setappdata(window,'flag',false);

    object = imread('D:/match.jpg');

    %Conversion from color to gray
    object = cv.cvtColor(object,'RGB2GRAY');

    %Declaring detector and extractor
    detector = cv.FeatureDetector('SURF');
    extractor = cv.DescriptorExtractor('SURF');

    %Calculating object keypoints
    objKeypoints = detector.detect(object);

    %Calculating object descriptors
    objDescriptors = extractor.compute(object,objKeypoints);

    % Start main loop
    while true
        % Grab and preprocess an image
        im = camera.read;
        %im = cv.resize(im,1);
        scene = cv.cvtColor(im,'RGB2GRAY');

        sceneKeypoints = detector.detect(scene);

        %Checking for empty keypoints
        if isempty(sceneKeypoints) 
            continue
        end;

        sceneDescriptors = extractor.compute(scene,sceneKeypoints);

        matcher = cv.DescriptorMatcher('BruteForce');
        matches = matcher.match(objDescriptors,sceneDescriptors);

        objDescriptRow = size(objDescriptors,1);
        dist_arr = zeros(1,objDescriptRow);


        for i=1:objDescriptRow
            dist_arr(i) = matches(i).distance;
        end;


        min_dist = min(dist_arr);

        N = 10000;    
        good_matches = repmat(struct('distance',0,'imgIdx',0,'queryIdx',0,'trainIdx',0), N, 1 );

        goodmatchesSize = 0;

        for i=1:objDescriptRow
            if matches(i).distance < 3 * min_dist
                good_matches(i).distance = matches(i).distance;
                good_matches(i).imgIdx = matches(i).imgIdx;
                good_matches(i).queryIdx = matches(i).queryIdx;
                good_matches(i).trainIdx = matches(i).trainIdx;

                %Recording the number of good matches
                goodmatchesSize = goodmatchesSize +1;
            end
        end

        im_matches = cv.drawMatches(object, objKeypoints, scene, sceneKeypoints,good_matches);

        objPoints = [];
        scnPoints = [];


        %Finding the good matches
        for i=1:goodmatchesSize

            qryIdx = good_matches(i).queryIdx;
            trnIdx = good_matches(i).trainIdx;
            if qryIdx == 0 
                continue 
            end;
            if trnIdx == 0
                continue
            end;

            first_point = objKeypoints(qryIdx).pt;
            second_point = sceneKeypoints(trnIdx).pt;

            objPoints(i,:)= (first_point);
            scnPoints(i,:) = (second_point);

        end

        %Error checking     
        if length(scnPoints) <=4
            continue
        end;
        if length(scnPoints)~= length(objPoints)
            continue
        end;


        % Finding homography of arrays of two sets of points 
        H = cv.findHomography(objPoints,scnPoints);


        objectCorners = [];
        sceneCorners =[];


        objectCorners(1,1) = 0.1;
        objectCorners(1,2) = 0.1;

        objectCorners(2,1) = size(object,2);
        objectCorners(2,2) = 0.1;

        objectCorners(3,1) = size(object,2);
        objectCorners(3,2) = size(object,1);

        objectCorners(4,1) = 0.1;
        objectCorners(4,2) = size(object,1);

        %Transposing the object corners for perpective transform to work
        newObj = shiftdim(objectCorners,-1);

        %Calculating the perspective tranform
        foo =cv.perspectiveTransform(newObj,H);
        sceneCorners = shiftdim(foo,1);

        offset = [];
        offset(1,1) = size(object,2);
        offset(1,2)= 0;


        outimg = cv.line(im_matches,sceneCorners(1,:)+offset,sceneCorners(2,:)+offset);
        outimg = cv.line(outimg,sceneCorners(2,:)+offset,sceneCorners(3,:)+offset);
        outimg = cv.line(outimg,sceneCorners(3,:)+offset,sceneCorners(4,:)+offset);
        outimg = cv.line(outimg,sceneCorners(4,:)+offset,sceneCorners(1,:)+offset);
        imshow(outimg);


     % Terminate if any user input
        flag = getappdata(window,'flag');
        if isempty(flag)||flag, break; end
        pause(0.000000001);
    end

% Close

    close(window);

end
```

Answer (score 0):

First obvious questions:

How do you know that the matches are good? Have you plotted them on top of the images to verify? Are you sure you are ordering the matches correctly when passing them to the fitting routine?

You note that the homography coefficients you get are "slightly" different, but absolute variations in them don't mean much, since a homography is only defined up to scale. What matters are the reprojection errors in image coordinates.

Comment: I saw the matches fitting within my test object , via imshow , the interest points in train object projects nicely on to my test image http://i.imgur.com/wCbTiVm.png . If you look carefully on the left corner you will notice a faint black line , this is the line which should a rectangle , not a obscure trapezoid . And also as I mentioned the perspective transform is giving me coordinates that has a nagging (0,0) coordinates , however , I move the image . About the reprojection error , can you please elaborate .

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a full homography? For this application an affine or even a similarity transformation (dx, dy, scale, and rotation) may be sufficient.  A more constrained transformation will work better in the presence of noise.

Comment: Okay , let me break it down to you . I am doing a project where I have to detect bank notes and tell its value to the user when he holds it near to a webcam . The problem is even though I could match a bank note to another , via homography , how would I tell the user 10 dollar note , or a 5 dollar note . So , I coded the whole OpenCV code in Matlab , since homography requires use of ransac algorithm which would enable me to calculate the number of inliers . The higher the number of inliers for a sample , the more similar is both the image ...continued...

Comment: Now , it turns out , OpenCV does not have an interface for checking out no of inlers , here I have to download ransac for Matlab , hoping that since the code is available , I can tweak it to give values of inliers, once a similar image is held close to it . Thats why I chose Matlab . Another fact is OpenCV implementation of ransac is , though fast , is closed source .

Comment: To answer your question , how would I apply affine tranformation ? And is my logic okay , just a cursive glance .

Comment: I don't know enough about opencvmex. See what options you have for the feature matcher to help you improve the accuracy of the initial matches. For example, there is a nearest-neighbor ratio approach used by David Lowe in his SIFT paper. See if there is a function to compute an affine transform using RANSAC. All of that, by the way, is available in the Computer Vision System Toolbox for MATLAB. There is a matchFeatures function that throws out ambiguous matches, and an estimateGeometricTransform function, that uses RANSAC, lets you choose a transform type, and gives you the number of inliers.

Comment: Try de-noising the image first. Then check the results of feature matching. These two are one of important steps in your code