# Issues with imgIdx in DescriptorMatcher mexopencv

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, mex

My idea is simple here. I am using `mexopencv` and trying to see whether there is any object present in my current that matches with any image stored in my database.I am using OpenCV `DescriptorMatcher` function to train my images.
Here is a snippet, I am wishing to build on top of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313863/updated-error-in-calculating-perspective-transform-for-opencv-in-matlab), which is one to one one image matching using `mexopencv`, and can also be extended for image stream.

```
function hello

    detector = cv.FeatureDetector('ORB');
    extractor = cv.DescriptorExtractor('ORB');
    matcher = cv.DescriptorMatcher('BruteForce-Hamming');

    train = [];
    for i=1:3
        train(i).img = [];
        train(i).points = [];
        train(i).features = [];    
    end;

    train(1).img = imread('D:\test\1.jpg');
    train(2).img = imread('D:\test\2.png');
    train(3).img = imread('D:\test\3.jpg');


    for i=1:3

        frameImage = train(i).img;
        framePoints = detector.detect(frameImage);
        frameFeatures = extractor.compute(frameImage , framePoints);

       train(i).points = framePoints;
       train(i).features = frameFeatures;

    end;

    for i = 1:3 
        boxfeatures = train(i).features;
        matcher.add(boxfeatures);
    end;
    matcher.train();

    camera = cv.VideoCapture;
    pause(3);%Sometimes necessary 

    window = figure('KeyPressFcn',@(obj,evt)setappdata(obj,'flag',true));
    setappdata(window,'flag',false);

    while(true)

      sceneImage = camera.read; 
      sceneImage = rgb2gray(sceneImage);

      scenePoints = detector.detect(sceneImage);
      sceneFeatures = extractor.compute(sceneImage,scenePoints);

      m = matcher.match(sceneFeatures);

      %{
      %Comments in
      img_no = m.imgIdx;
      img_no = img_no(1);

      %I am planning to do this based on the fact that
      %on a perfect match imgIdx a 1xN will be filled
      %with the index of the training  
      %example 1,2 or 3 

      objPoints = train(img_no+1).points;
      boxImage = train(img_no+1).img;

      ptsScene = cat(1,scenePoints([m.queryIdx]+1).pt);
      ptsScene = num2cell(ptsScene,2);

      ptsObj = cat(1,objPoints([m.trainIdx]+1).pt);
      ptsObj = num2cell(ptsObj,2);

      %This is where the problem starts here, assuming the 
      %above is correct , Matlab yells this at me 
      %index exceeds matrix dimensions.

      end [H,inliers] = cv.findHomography(ptsScene,ptsObj,'Method','Ransac');
      m = m(inliers);

      imgMatches = cv.drawMatches(sceneImage,scenePoints,boxImage,boxPoints,m,...
       'NotDrawSinglePoints',true);
      imshow(imgMatches);

     %Comment out
     %}

      flag = getappdata(window,'flag');
      if isempty(flag) || flag, break; end
      pause(0.0001);

end
```

Now the issue here is that `imgIdx` is a 1xN matrix , and it contains the index of different training indices, which is obvious. And only on a perfect match is the matrix `imgIdx` is completely filled with the matched image index. **So, how do I use this matrix to pick the right image index. Also 
in these two lines, I get the error of index exceeding matrix dimension.**

```
ptsObj = cat(1,objPoints([m.trainIdx]+1).pt);
ptsObj = num2cell(ptsObj,2);
```

This is obvious since while debugging I saw clearly that the size of `m.trainIdx` is greater than `objPoints`, i.e I am accessing points which I should not, hence index exceeds 
There is scant documentation on use of `imgIdx` , so anybody who has knowledge on this subject, I need help.
These are the images I used.

```
Image1
```

[image: Image1]

```
Image2
```

[image: Image2]

```
Image3
```

[image: Image3]

#### 1st update after @Amro's response:

```
With the ratio of min distance to distance at 3.6 , I get the following response.
```

[image: For 3.6]

```
With the ratio of min distance to distance at 1.6 , I get the following response.
```

[image: For 1.6]

Comment: @Amro: If you are not busy, can I have a helping hand out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is easier to explain with code, so here it goes :)

```
%% init
detector = cv.FeatureDetector('ORB');
extractor = cv.DescriptorExtractor('ORB');
matcher = cv.DescriptorMatcher('BruteForce-Hamming');

urls = {
    'http://i.imgur.com/8Pz4M9q.jpg?1'
    'http://i.imgur.com/1aZj0MI.png?1'
    'http://i.imgur.com/pYepuzd.jpg?1'
};

N = numel(urls);
train = struct('img',cell(N,1), 'pts',cell(N,1), 'feat',cell(N,1));

%% training
for i=1:N
    % read image
    train(i).img = imread(urls{i});
    if ~ismatrix(train(i).img)
        train(i).img = rgb2gray(train(i).img);
    end

    % extract keypoints and compute features
    train(i).pts = detector.detect(train(i).img);
    train(i).feat = extractor.compute(train(i).img, train(i).pts);

    % add to training set to match against
    matcher.add(train(i).feat);
end
% build index
matcher.train();

%% testing
% lets create a distorted query image from one of the training images
% (rotation+shear transformations)
t = -pi/3;    % -60 degrees angle
tform = [cos(t) -sin(t) 0; 0.5*sin(t) cos(t) 0; 0 0 1];
img = imwarp(train(3).img, affine2d(tform));    % try all three images here!

% detect fetures in query image
pts = detector.detect(img);
feat = extractor.compute(img, pts);

% match against training images
m = matcher.match(feat);

% keep only good matches
%hist([m.distance])
m = m([m.distance] < 3.6*min([m.distance]));

% sort by distances, and keep at most the first/best 200 matches
[~,ord] = sort([m.distance]);
m = m(ord);
m = m(1:min(200,numel(m)));

% naive classification (majority vote)
tabulate([m.imgIdx])    % how many matches each training image received
idx = mode([m.imgIdx]);

% matches with keypoints belonging to chosen training image
mm = m([m.imgIdx] == idx);

% estimate homography (used to locate object in query image)
ptsQuery = num2cell(cat(1, pts([mm.queryIdx]+1).pt), 2);
ptsTrain = num2cell(cat(1, train(idx+1).pts([mm.trainIdx]+1).pt), 2);
[H,inliers] = cv.findHomography(ptsTrain, ptsQuery, 'Method','Ransac');

% show final matches
imgMatches = cv.drawMatches(img, pts, ...
    train(idx+1).img, train(idx+1).pts, ...
    mm(logical(inliers)), 'NotDrawSinglePoints',true);

% apply the homography to the corner points of the training image
[h,w] = size(train(idx+1).img);
corners = permute([0 0; w 0; w h; 0 h], [3 1 2]);
p = cv.perspectiveTransform(corners, H);
p = permute(p, [2 3 1]);

% show where the training object is located in the query image
opts = {'Color',[0 255 0], 'Thickness',4};
imgMatches = cv.line(imgMatches, p(1,:), p(2,:), opts{:});
imgMatches = cv.line(imgMatches, p(2,:), p(3,:), opts{:});
imgMatches = cv.line(imgMatches, p(3,:), p(4,:), opts{:});
imgMatches = cv.line(imgMatches, p(4,:), p(1,:), opts{:});
imshow(imgMatches)
```

The result:

[image: object_detection]

Note that since you did not post any testing images (in your code you are taking input from the webcam), I created one by distorting one the training images, and using it as a query image. I am using functions from certain MATLAB toolboxes (`imwarp` and such), but those are non-essential to the demo and you could replace them with equivalent OpenCV ones...

I must say that this approach is not the most robust one.. Consider using other techniques such as the [bag-of-word model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision), which OpenCV already [implements](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/object_categorization.html).

Comment: I am actually trying to distinguish between two very similar images, for example between two bank notes, which have very similar histogram.Bag of words is good for distinguishing images having non-similar histogram characteristic as far as I know. Distinguishing between piano and say a flower would be apropos for bag of word model.

Comment: @whoknows: I see. How did the above approach perform on your actual data?

Comment: I have modified the ratio of distance to 1.6 and I received the response in the updates. Should I continue to use 1.6 since I got good response before, in calculating homography when I used live streaming and with only one sample as training example.Any thoughts?

Comment: Okay, its giving good results, I am in the testing process; trying to tweak in the ratio of the distances.

Comment: Thanks , I think I owe you a coffee or something. Hopefully, I will come again to disturb you.

Comment: ah, I was experimenting with different values for the multiplier `k`, I just forgot to set it back to something smaller..

Comment: Just a point to note, why isn't there a proper documentation for mexopencv , I got this one thus far, http://www.cs.stonybrook.edu/~kyamagu/mexopencv/matlab/BOWKMeansTrainer.html, but it would be helpful, if there were a few more words added to the method call descriptor for you know, beginners usage.

Comment: @whoknows: `mexopencv` is just a wrapper, so the main source of [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/) is that of OpenCV itself.

Comment: Yep,I know that. I think I saw some of your samples in github, amazing work notheless from you and that other guy.

Comment: thanks the credit goes to Kota Yamaguchi, it is his project :)

Comment: Was there any reason to choose the first 200 best matches. I think the outliers were already rejected when ratio test of good matches distance done was with the min distance. Is choosing 200 best matches totally empirical, any reasons?

Comment: @whoknows: it was just another ad-hoc filtering step (it didnt make much difference in the case above). And yes the value `200` was completely arbitrary, I just wanted to put an upper cap on the number of matches :)

Comment: Hi, I was wondering what the default values that are normally used for example here `detector = cv.FeatureDetector('ORB')` in order to describe the number of descriptors that I need to choose, or the thresholding values. I was looking here,http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#orb-orb, and saw some "pre-initialized" values. Are these used by default in mexopencv, most importantly are these values used in OpenCV to begin with. If not, then what values are used.Thanks.

Comment: @whoknows: yes the default values are used in both OpenCV and mexopencv. In fact in MATLAB you can call `get(detector)` on the object to see the list of all properties and their values. You see the `features2d` module exposes two interfaces to create detectors: one using a specific detector class (as in `cv.ORB(...)`), the other using a generic interface which abstracts common functionality of all detectors (as in `cv.FeatureDetector('ORB')`).

Comment: @whoknows: ... The former directly calls the C++ class constructor [`ORB::ORB`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#orb-orb), the latter calls the C++ factory function [`FeatureDetector::create`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#featuredetector-create) which in turn instantiate the detector by name. The advantage of the common interface is that it allows you to easily switch between the different underlying algorithms for feature-detection. Same applies for descriptor-extractors.