# Extracting a 3x3 matrix from an image

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

I need to extract a 3x3 matrix from an image and store it separately, and it should continue like this till the end of image. For example, my image is the following matrix:

```
p = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; ...
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; ...
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; ...
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; ...
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; ...
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]
```

The output should be like this:

```
p1 = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3]
p2 = [4 5 6; 4 5 6; 4 5 6]
p3 = [7 8 9; 7 8 9; 7 8 9]
```

and so on....

Can you please suggest me code or a built-in function for this?

Comment: @ZoranPlesivčak MATLAB interprets matrix definitions just fine without ellipses. They are superfluous in this case.

Comment: @EitanT I didn't know that... Maybe you should revert my change.

Comment: @ZoranPlesivčak It doesn't really matter. You can do it too, if you want.

Comment: -1: I don't agree with the initial upvote. *Can you please suggest me code or a built-in function* shows lack of research effort. In addtion: Why do you have to extract the matrix and generate additional matrices? Why is indexing and performing computations in-place not an option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to divide a matrix into equals parts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817174/), [divide the image into 3*3 blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972684/), [Divide a matrix into submatrices in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554522/) and many more...

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to extract submatrices:

```
p1 = img(1:3, 1:3);
p2 = img(4:6, 4:6);
p3 = img(7:9, 7:9);
```

---

Function for doing slicing.

```
function imgsl = img_slice( img, ry, rx )
    [ Y X ] = meshgrid(ry, rx);
    imgsl = reshape(img(sub2ind(size(img),Y(:),X(:))),[length(rx) length(ry)]).';
```

Use it as follows:

```
p1 = img_slice( p, 1:3, 1:3 );
p2 = img_slice( p, 4:6, 4:6 );
p3 = img_slice( p, 7:9, 7:9 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The image processing toolbox has a `im2col` function [(link)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html).

```
B = im2col(p, [3 3], 'distinct');
```

Then each column of `B` is a 3x3 block made into a vector, and you can use `reshape(B(:, i), 3, 3)` to recover the i-th 3x3 block. Note there are zeros padded to `p`.